# Issue with BETWEEN in CASE statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to schedule automatic task which will pull data based on the current month. The tricky part is that it needs to pull a weird date (e.g. from 01.15 to 02.17) every month. I've tried the below but it's saying that there's an issue with my BETWEEN statement.

```
WHERE
 CASE WHEN
 DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,  GETDATE() ), 0) = '2017-05'
THEN 
CAST(<here_is_the_date_column>) AS date) BETWEEN '2017-04-23' AND '2017-05-23'
```

Comment: What kind of date is "01.15" and "02.17"?  Please be clearer on what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` _expressions_ in `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use the case expression as flow control (like an if..else), but case is an expression, meaning it returns a single scalar value, and it can't be used like this. It's even stated in the [`case` MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql):

> The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures. For a list of control-of-flow methods, see Control-of-Flow Language (Transact-SQL).

What you need is `and` and `or`:

```
WHERE  
(
   DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,  GETDATE() ), 0) = '2017-05-01'
   AND CAST(<here_is_the_date_column>) AS date) BETWEEN '2017-04-23' AND '2017-05-23'
)  
OR -- Here comes the part you would use for the `else` part of the case statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a compound logical expression instead like

```
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,  GETDATE() ), 0) = '2017-05-01'
AND 
CAST(<here_is_the_date_column>) AS date) BETWEEN '2017-04-23' AND '2017-05-23'
```

Comment: WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,  GETDATE() ), 0) = '2017-05' ??? You cannot supply a partial date. You HAVE to supply a day as well, e.g. '2017-05-01'. THAT's why the downvote.

Comment: @RachelAmbler, that's per OP's post and moreover that's not the point of my answer

Comment: You supplied an ANSWER - your answer is WRONG as a result. Don't blame me because you screwed up YOUR answer. If the OP tries your answer they'll get "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' as a result. An answer is meant to help the OP, NOT to confuse them still more.

Comment: @RachelAmbler While your comment is correct, IMHO that's not enough to downvote an answer. I think my answer is better not because I've fixed the problem you are talking about (and let's be fair, I only saw it after reading your comment), but because it supplies the explanation missing from Rahul's answer.

Comment: @RachelAmbler, Yeah right *answer meant to help* and not spoon feed. you should never copy/paste answer blindly. My answer gives the right point which OP missing

Comment: SO has no rules as to why you can downvote an answer. Your answer was correct so I upvoted it. It's a tough world out there and I've been downvoted several times.

Comment: @Rahul I've taken the liberty to edit your answer and add that missing `-01` so that I would be able to upvote it.

Comment: @RachelAmbler hence IMHO.